# Why copy constructor is not called in this case?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Here is the little code snippet:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int value) : value_(value)
    {
        cout <<"Regular constructor" <<endl;
    }

    A(const A& other)   : value_(other.value_)  
    {
        cout <<"Copy constructor" <<endl;
    }

private:
    int value_;
};
int main()
{
    A a = A(5);
}
```

I assumed that output would be "Regular Constructor" (for RHS) followed by "Copy constructor" for LHS. So I avoided this style and always declared variable of class as `A a(5);`.  But to my surprise in the code above copy constructor is never called (Visual C++ 2008)

Does anybody know if this behavior is a result of compiler optimization, or some documented (and portable) feature of C++? Thanks.

Comment: it's optimized, avoiding construct+copying. I find that it's a good assumption that no user would construct from parameters, differently from what it's done copy-constructing

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394229/understanding-return-value-optimization-and-returning-temporaries-c

Comment: In g++, you can disable this optimization with the option -fno-elide-constructors

Answer (score 15):

From another comment: "So by default I should not rely on it (as it may depend on the compiler)"

No, it does not depend on the compiler, practically anyway. Any compiler worth a grain of sand won't waste time constructing an A, then copying it over.

In the standard it explicitly says that it is completely acceptable for `T = x;` to be equivalent to saying `T(x);`. (§12.8.15, pg. 211) Doing this with `T(T(x))` is obviously redundant, so it removes the inner `T`.

To get the desired behavior, you'd force the compiler to default construct the first A:

```
A a;
// A is now a fully constructed object,
// so it can't call constructors again:
a = A(5);
```

Comment: Thanks GMan, I never use this syntax anyway. Just something to remember. Oh, just found on msdn: C++ standard allows the elision of the copy constructor (see section 12.8. Copying class objects, paragraph 15)

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. It's a bit much to quote in an answer, so I'll just refer it by number.

Comment: It depends on compiler. Standard allows different behavior, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I was researching this to answer another question that was closed as a dupe, so in order to not let the work go to waste I 'm answering this one instead.

A statement of the form `A a = A(5)` is called *copy-initialization* of the variable `a`. The C++11 standard, 8.5/16 states:

> The function selected is called with the initializer expression as
>   its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a
>   temporary of the cv-unqualified version of the destination type. The
>   temporary is a prvalue. The result of the call (which is the temporary
>   for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize, according
>   to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the
>   copy-initialization. **In certain cases, an implementation is permitted
>   to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization by
>   constructing the intermediate result directly into the object being
>   initialized; see 12.2, 12.8**.

This means that the compiler looks up the appropriate constructor to handle `A(5)`, creates a temporary and copies that temporary into `a`. But under what circumstances can the copy be eliminated?

Let's see what 12.8/31 says:

> **When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.** In
>   such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the
>   omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways of referring
>   to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the
>   later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed
>   without the optimization. This elision of copy/move operations,
>   called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances
>   (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> [...]
>
> - **when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type**, the copy/move operation can be
>     omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

Having all this in mind, here's what happens with the expression `A a = A(5)`:

1. The compiler sees a declaration with copy-initialization
2. The `A(int)` constructor is selected to initialize a temporary object
3. Because the temporary object is *not* bound to a reference, and it does have the same type `A` as the destination type in the copy-initialization expression, the compiler is permitted to directly construct an object into `a`, eliding the temporary

Answer (score 4):

Here you have *copy-initialization* of `a` from temporary `A(5)`. Implementation allowed to skip calling copy constructor here according to C++ Standard 12.2/2.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  The example in 12.2.2 involves a temporary being passed to a function before constructing the local object.

Answer (score -1):

```
A a = A(5);
```

This line is equivalent to

```
A a(5);
```

Despite its function-style appearance, the first line simply constructs `a` with the argument 5.  No copying or temporaries are involved.  From the C++ standard, section 12.1.11:

> A functional notation type conversion (5.2.3) can be used to create new objects of its type. [ Note: The
>   syntax looks like an explicit call of the constructor. —end note ]

Comment: No, it's not equivalent.  One is *copy-initialization*, the other is *direct-initialization*.