# I'm confused about copy-constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why copy constructor is not called in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case)

In the following code, I constructed three variables, a1, a2 and a3.

There's a example in C++ Primer p.476:

```
string empty_copy = string();//copy-initialization
```

Is there anyone can help me explain

1)why a1 and a2 are not constructed by copy constructor and

2)what's the difference between initialization a2 in my code and empty_copy in the book?

Thanks so much!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    A(){}
    A(int v){}
    A(const A&x){
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
    }
};
A generateA(){
    return A(0);
}
int main(){
        cout<<"First:"<<endl;
        A a1=generateA();

        cout<<"Second:"<<endl;
        A a2=A(0);

        cout<<"Third:"<<endl;
        A a3=a1;
    return 0;
}
```

The out put is (under Visual Studio 2010 in Win7 and g++ in Ubuntu10.10):

```
First:
Second:
Third:
copy constructor
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is copy elision due to **[Return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)**.
Compilers are allowed to optimze away generation of copies by applying such optimizations.

```
A a1=generateA(); 
A a2=A(0);
```

In the above both cases the compiler can eliminate the creation of a temporary object which is created to hold the return value.

```
A a3=a1;
```

Involves a already existing named object `a1` which is used for construction of `a3` this involves a copy constructor call which the compiler must make and cannot optimize.

**EDIT:**  To answer the Q in comment.

You can tell the compiler to not apply this optimization by using the following options during compilation:

For **GCC:**

```
-fno-elide-constructors
```

For **MVSC:**

```
/Od
```

Comment: And *also* copy elision due to initialization from a temporary. So both kinds of elision are used.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, is there any method to disable optimization?

Comment: @user1265982: Yes.Please check the updated answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

1. The copy constructor is not used in for `a1` and `a2` because in both cases you are passing an `int` and therefore the compiler is using the `A(int)` constructor you've defined.
2. The difference between yours and the example from the book, is that the book is creating an instance on the stack (`string()`), and therefore getting an empty-copy, whilst in your case, you are using an *existing* instance (`a1`).  Both are using the copy constructor for initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

When you initializa a1, you have an integer argument (given in your factory function). For a2 you also pass an integer. For a3 you say that a3=a1. This is interpreted as a3(a1) as you have a copy constructor defined, and so it is called.