# Copy Constructor didn't call, why?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why copy constructor is not called in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case)

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

class test {  
    int *p;  
public:
    test operator=(test a);
    test()  {
        p = new int [2];
        cout <<"Default Constructor was done here." << "\n";
    }

    test(const test &a) {
        p = new int [2];
        this->p[0] = a.p[0];
        this->p[1] = a.p[1];
        cout << "Copy Constructor was done here." << "\n";
    }

    ~test() {
        delete p;
        cout << "Destructor was done here." << "\n";
    }
    int set (int a, int b) {
        p[0] = a;
        p[1] = b;
        return 1;
    }

    int show () {
        cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << "\n";
        return 2;
    }
};    

test test::operator=(test a) {
    p[0] = a.p[0]; 
    p[1] = a.p[1]; 
    cout << "Operator = was done here" << "\n";
    return *this;
}

test f(test x) {
    x.set(100, 100);
    return x;
}

int main () {
    test first;
    test second;
    first.set(12, 12);

    //f(first);
    //second = first;
    second = f(first);


    first.show();
    second.show();

    getchar ();
    return 0;
}
```

Copy Constructor was called only three times? Why?
If I understand, we made four copies (we send object to func, func returns value, we send object to operator=, operator= returns value).

Comment: Copy elision, lots of duplicates...

Answer (score 3):

This is likely an effect of [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). The compiler is free to avoid copying objects wherever it doesn't make an impact on the program. Side effects of copy-constructor/destructor are not considered as an impact on the program in this caser. In general it will avoid copying a temporary for use as a function parameter, since the temporary would be destroyed afterwards anyways.

This can be found in §12.8.32 in the standard:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class  object, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and/or destructor for the object have side eﬀects. In such
>   cases,  the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted
>   copy/move operation as simply two diﬀerent  ways of referring to the
>   same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of
>   the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the
>   optimization. This elision of copy/move 
>   operations, called copyelision, is permitted in the following
>   circumstances (which maybe combined to  eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when    the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object with
>     the same cv-unqualiﬁed type as the function return type, the
>     copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic
>     object directly into the function’s return value
> - in a throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile    automatic object whose scope does not extend beyond
>     the end of the    innermost enclosing try-block (if there is one), the
>     copy/move    operation from the operand to the exception object (15.1)
>     can be    omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into
>     the    exception object
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to  a reference    (12.2) would becopied/moved to a class object witht he
>     same    cv-unqualiﬁed type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by 
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>     omitted copy/move
> - when the exception-declaration of an exception handler (Clause 15)       declares an object of the same type (except for cv-qualiﬁcation) as
>     the exception object (15.1), the copy/move operation can be omitted
>     bytreatingthe exception-declaration as an alias for the exception
>     object if the meaning of the program will be unchanged except for the 
>     execution of constructors and destructors for the object declared by
>     the exception-declaration.

In this case it will likely simply use the object returned by `f` as input for the `operator=`, since it is a temporary and would therefore be destroyed right afterwards anyways.

Comment: Is output not observable behaviour?

Comment: Compiler is allowed to elide copies even if they have side effects.

Comment: @BoBTFish it is, but the answer is wrong. "The compiler is free to avoid copying objects wherever it doesn't make an impact on the program" - this part is incorrect.

Comment: The compiler is free to avoid *anything* whenever it doesn't make an impact on the program.  It makes a special case for copying as jrok and Luchian pointed out.