# copy constructor c++ on temporary objects

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;

public:
    A(int c) : x(c) {}
    A(const A& a) { x = a.x; cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;}
};

class B
{
    A a;

public:
    B(int c) : a(c) {}
    B(const B& b) : a(b.a) { }
    A get_A() { return a;}
};

int main()
{
    B b(10);
    A a1 = b.get_A();

}
```

In the code above, I expected that 'copy constructor called' message would pop up twice because first, the b.get_A() will create a temporary object which invokes copy constructor (1) and second, it will copy its reference to a1 's copy constructor (2) , thus making two messages showing up.

However, the code actually results a single 'copy constructor called' message. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why copy constructor is not called in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ standard allows for the [copy constructor to be elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in certain situations.  Typically, this means if an object will be copy constructed from a temporary variable.  It can be constructed in place.

In this case `get_A();` has returned a copy, into a temporary.  You then assign `a1` to that temporary variable.  The compiler is allowed to elide the extra copy and construct `a1` in place with the return value of `get_A()`.

This optimization can occur, even when the copy constructor has side effects.

> Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization that can change the observable side-effects. Because some compilers do not perform copy elision in every situation where it is allowed, programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portable.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 the code might invoke a move constructor to move the object rather than copy it or in both C++03 and C++11  compiler optimizations in the form of NRVO might apply **[copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)** to elide the copy.

Note that latter(*copy elision*) depends on capability of the compiler and is not guaranteed while former(*Move semantics*) is guaranteed in C++11.

Comment: I used visual studio 2012 (which supports c++11) and move constructor did not invoked :(

Comment: A(const A&& a) { x = a.x; cout << "move called" <<endl;}
I added this code to class A

Comment: @LeeJaeBeom: Typically, all good compilers will apply copy elision optimization but note that the compiler doesn't have to apply this optimization. It is not guaranteed. On gcc you can use the `-fno-elide-constructors` setting to check the behavior by exlicitly disabling copy elision.

Comment: @AlokSave; thanks, i can see temporary `constructors` and `destructors` now.