# Template class copy constructor not called

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, copy-elision

My copy constructor is not being called and I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPtr
{
    public:
        explicit SmartPtr(T *p) : m_p(p) { cout << "ctor" << endl; }
        SmartPtr(const SmartPtr& p) : m_p(p.m_p) { cout << "copy ctor" << endl;}

    private:
        T* m_p;
};

int main()
{
    SmartPtr<int> pt4 = SmartPtr<int>(new int);
}
```

The output is only "ctor". It looks like a default copy constructor is used. If I add "explicit" then it doesn't compile, giving the error:

```
"error: no matching function for call to ‘SmartPtr<int>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr<int>)’"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The copy is being elided. Search for "copy elision".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why copy constructor is not called in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case)

Comment: @stefaanv First time here I've seen the accepted answer be actually wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is known as [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). It's a nice optimization where a copy clearly isn't necessary. Instead of effectively running the code:

```
SmartPtr<int> __tmp(new int);
SmartPtr<int> ptr4(__tmp);
__tmp.~SmartPtr<int>();
```

The compiler can know that `__tmp` only exists to construct `ptr4`, and thus is allowed to construct `__tmp` in-place in the memory owned by `ptr4` **as if** the actual code originally run was just:

```
SmartPtr<int> ptr4(new int);
```

Note that you can tell the compiler NOT to do this too. For instance, on gcc, you can pass the `-fno-elide-constructors` option and with that single change (additionally logging the destructor), now your code prints:

```
ctor
copy ctor // not elided!
dtor      
dtor      // extra SmartPtr!
```

See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73df213e68f5463b).

In the standard, §12.8:

> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - In a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when ...
> - In a *throw-expression*, when ...
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
> - when the *exception-declaration* of an exception handler (Clause 15) ...
>
> [*Example:*
>
> ```
> class Thing {
> public:
>     Thing();
>     ~Thing();
>     Thing(const Thing&);
> };
>
> Thing f() {
>     Thing t;
>     return t;
> }
>
> Thing t2 = f();
> ```
>
> Here the criteria for elision can be combined to eliminate two calls to the copy constructor of class `Thing`:
>   the copying of the local automatic object t into the temporary object for the return value of function `f()`
>   and the copying of that temporary object into object `t2`. Effectively, the construction of the local object `t`
>   can be viewed as directly initializing the global object `t2`, and that object’s destruction will occur at program
>   exit. Adding a move constructor to Thing has the same effect, but it is the move construction from the
>   temporary object to `t2` that is elided. *—end example* ]

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't adding "explicit" work? It seems like the compiler doesn't bother instantiating the copy constructor.

Comment: @SyedH Because the copy constructor is called implicitly in your code. If you want to call it explicitly, you'd have to do `SmartPtr<int> pt4(SmartPtr<int>(new int));`

Comment: I thought assignment at the same time as declaration uses the copy constructor. In which case, why is that line implicit conversion? What is it being converted from? Both types look the same. Anyhow, I changed the code just like you have it but the compiler still complains the same way: `no matching function for call to 'SmartPtr<int>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr<int>)'`

Comment: @SyedH Shouldn't. Doesn't for me.

Comment: Bizarre. Should I create a new question for this? To be clear, my c-ctor looks like this `explicit SmartPtr(const SmartPtr& p) : m_p(p.m_p) { cout << "copy ctor" << endl;}` and the call looks like this `SmartPtr<int> pt(SmartPtr<int>(new int));`. The rest of the class is the same as above. I'm using **gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)**.

Comment: @SyedH Naw, likely gcc bug that they fixed sometime in the last **seven** years. Get a new compiler :)