# what function were called when initiate a string with both char array and = operator

Tags: c++, string, copy

According to the explanation in C++ primer 5th.

Initiate a string with char array and using `=`
operator. It will actually do below two things:

1: Call constructor which accept a `const char *` to create a temporary `string object`.

2: Call copy constructor to initiate the true variable;

> chapter 13.1  page 618
>   string null_book = "9-999-99999-9"; // copy initialization

I made a test. and it seems that when I initiate A object with a cahr array.
copy construtor have never been called.

```
#include <iostream>
int b =5;
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A(const char * ch) :chr(*ch) {cout << "contruct ";};
    A(const A & a) : chr(0) {cout << "copy_construc ";::b = 2;}  ;
    A &operator=(const A & a)  {cout << "assignment"; return *this;};
    char chr;
};

int main() {
    A a = "qweqeasd";
    cout << b;
    cout << a.chr;
    A c = A("wrwsx");
    cout << b;
    cout << c.chr;
}
```

output:

```
contruct 5qcontruct 5w
```

Comment: It's not because there is an `=` that it's going to be a copy constructor.

Comment: why, I did not even initiate the object

Comment: Yes, exactly. It will call the constructor with your value. Normal construction. Yes, the duplicate is not the best one here.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yeah you're right I misread, maybe you can provide a better one?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758142/why-copy-constructor-is-not-called-in-this-case even if there is no explicit `A` in this case, but explains what happens as if OP wrote `A a = A("xxxx");`?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Thanks, I think that question is the same with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is called [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

```
A a = "qweqeasd";
```

> If `T` is a class type and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is T or a class derived from T, the non-explicit constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. **The constructor is then called to initialize the object.**

Here the best match is the constructor `A(const char * ch)` and that is why the output starts with `contruct` .

Comment: please stop answering duplicates, especially when they are already mentioned.

Comment: I answered **after** the post was reopened after being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I gave a possible duplicate, and we were discussing duplicates. For an almost gold badge, this is a shame.

Comment: Well, the goldbadge holder was mistaken, your comment suggested that you were not sure (maybe...). It's still not closed as a dupe after nearly two hours when such things happen within minutes.  There is only one close vote on it.  Let's not "shame" others.