# How to make C++ compiler call copy constructor when generating a temporary object?

Tags: c++

Quoted from [In C++, a Copy Constructor may be called in following cases:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-13/?ref=rp)

> 1. When an object of the class is returned by value.
> 2. When an object of the class is passed (to a function) by value as an argument.
> 3. When an object is constructed based on another object of the same class.
> 4. When compiler generates a temporary object.

I think the context is about the legacy C++ rather than the modern one.

## My comments

- Option 1. The copy ctor may not be called due to copy elision on "returning an object as well as a temporary object by value" provided by modern c++.

```cpp
Foo Method1(){return Foo{};}
Foo Method2(){Foo obj{}; return obj;}
```

- Option 2. The copy ctor will not be called due to copy elision on "passing a temporary object by value" provided by modern c++.

```cpp
void Method3(Foo param){}
Method3(Foo{});
```

- Option 3. The copy ctor will not be called due to copy elision on "initializing object by a temporary object" provided by modern c++.

```cpp
Foo obj {Foo{}};
```

- Option 4. I don't understand this option. I cannot find any example how compiler calls copy constructor when generating a temporary object. I did compile with legacy C++ (with `-fno-elide-constructors`) and modern C++, they both do *NOT* call the copy constructor. Or is the option 4 wrong?

Comment: Historically, have the legacy c++ called copy constructor when generating a temporary object? Honestly, it does not make sense. What is the purpose of calling copy constructor when generating a temporary object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945598/11971304, here's something for reference. Modern c++ compilers still would prefer elision for temporary objects copy. if you are looking for an answer which says "what version of c++ compiler is required to invoke a copy constructor for temporary object creation" then that changes the context of question!.

Comment: How "legacy" do you want to get?  We can go all the way to 1982's "CFront" if you want... :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: From the first C++ created by Bjarne Stroustrup. :-)

Comment: "Or is the option 4 wrong?" No, the full absence of a compiler with this behavior is no evidence, that this option is not standard compliant. Good question however! I guess there's no robust way to force that for all standard-conform modern compilers even before C++17's guaranteed copy elision, but cannot prove it.