# Template class implicit copy constructor issues

Tags: templates, copy-constructor

Stepping through my program in gdb, line 108 returns right back to the calling function, and doesn't call the copy constructor in class A, like (I thought) it should:

```
template <class S> class A{
    //etc...
    A( const A & old ){
        //do stuff...
    }
    //etc...
};

template <class T> class B{
    //etc...
    A<T> ReturnsAnA(){
        A<T> result;
        // do some stuff with result
        return result; //line 108
    }
    //etc...
};
```

Any hints?  I've banged my head against the wall about this for 4 hours now, and can't seem to come up with what's happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[(Named) return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is in effect. Your copy constructor is being removed as an optimization (this is permitted by the standard although results in different behavior).

See also [Understanding return value optimization and returning temporaries - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394229/understanding-return-value-optimization-and-returning-temporaries-c).

(Templates have nothing to do with this.)