# const char* in my class has junk character(s) after it's returned from function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Class:

```
class myclass {
  public:
    myclass(void);

    const char* server;

  private:
    char pidchar[6];
    int pidnum;

};
```

The function

```
myclass parseINI(const char* file)
{
    myclass iniOptions;
    CSimpleIniA ini;
    ini.SetUnicode();
    ini.LoadFile(file);
    const char* server = ini.GetValue("", "server", "");
    iniOptions.server = server;
    std::cout << server << "\n"; // Prints the correct value here
    fflush(stdout);
    return iniOptions;


}
```

Calling it from the main function

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{

 myclass options;
 options = parseINI("myapp.ini");
 std::cout << options.server << "\n"; // It prints junk here
 return 0;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const char*` returned by `GetValue()` probably belonged to the `ini` object.  When you exited the `parseIni()` function, `ini` went out of scope and was destroyed, which could mean your pointer is no longer valid.

Try using a `std::string` for the `server` member type instead of `const char*`.

Comment: If `CSimpleINIA` is modifiable, this is definitely better.

Comment: The suggested change is to `myclass`, not `CSimpleIniA`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of std::string which will create a local copy.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using memory that is released when `CSimpleIniA` goes out of scope in `parseINI`.

```
const char* server = ini.GetValue("", "server", "");
iniOptions.server = server;
```

Copy the value that is returned into a new memory block before you return from the `parseINI` function.

```
string server = ini.GetValue("", "server", "");
iniOptions.server = new char[server.length() + 1];
std::copy(server.begin(), server.end(), iniOptions.server);         
iniOptions.server[server.length()] = 0;
```

Comment: @Martin - just pointing out where the error was while I tried out the alternative.

Comment: @codefrog - edited this in.  If you can change the struct to contain a `string`, that's better though (per @aschepler).

Comment: I'm getting this: error C2065: 'data' : undeclared identifier

Comment: A problem in my cut and paste, sorry - check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* server = ini.GetValue("", "server", "");
```

This value is falling out of scope when the function terminates, so when you assign the value of that pointer to your object's server pointer, the place in memory they point to is having its memory freed off the stack at the end of the function, and it's then overtaken by other things.

Using a std::string or even just a char[] will be preferred to just fix the problem with the least amount of changes, as they will by assigned the actual value and not a location in memory like pointers.

What you really should do is look up referential transparency, though. That will prevent problems like this from occurring ever again

Answer (score 1):

I's guess that the lifetime of the data pointed to by the `char*` returned from `CSimpleIniA::GetValue()` is the same as the `CSimpleIni` object itself.  So when `ini` is destructed, the pointer returned from `GetValue()` becomes invalid. (I've never used CSimpleIni, and haven't looked at the docs carefully enough to know for sure, but that's what the behavior points to).

I'd suggest changing `myclass::server` to be a `std:string` object and set it using something like:

```
iniOptions.server = std::string(server);
```

which will give the `myclass::server` object it's own copy of the string data.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using class as a function returned data type in C++ is totally wrong.
In C++ there are 2 kinds of data type: value type, reference type.
class belongs to second one;  From a function you can return a value type data or a pointer of any data.But you cann't retun a entity of a reference type. Because a entity of a reference type will be released right after the code reached out of the scope which the entity is defined.

You can do in either way:

1: 
define parseINI as:

```
     myclass* parseINI(const char* file) 
     {     
           myclass* iniOptions = new myclass();
           ........
           return iniOptions;   
      }
```

and then use it like this:

```
      myclass* options = parseINI("myapp.ini");
```

2:
define parseINI as:

```
       void parseINI(myclass& options, const char* file) 
        {     
           ........//asigne value to options's members
        }
```

and then use it like this:

```
        myclass options;
        parseINI(options,"myapp.ini");
```

3: 
Do what you did, but add a asignment method (operator=)  to myclass

Answer (score 0):

iniOptions is located on the stack and disposed automatically when the function returns. You should allocate it on heap using `new()`

Comment: Dear god, don't forget to attempt a delete in the deconstructor, though.

Comment: This should not matter, due to RVO.  The issue is the use of other stack-allocated memory via `ini`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394229/understanding-return-value-optimization-and-returning-temporaries-c

Comment: Even without RVO, this will not cause a problem (unless a class has a bad copy constructor, which is not the case this time).  There is no good reason here not to return a class object by value.

Comment: There are containers already designed for holding strings that create and delete the memory correctly please use them they are refereed to as std::string.

Comment: @Martin York, please use punctuation.  :)

Comment: @Dima: There is a full stop at the end.

Comment: @Martin You need two more and a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the local variable `server` points to a character buffer returned by `ini.GetValue()`, which is destroyed when `paraseINI()` returns.

One way to fix this is to allocate a new buffer yourself and copy the characters.

```
const char* server = ini.GetValue("", "server", "");
int length = strlen(server) + 1;  // length of the string +1 for the NULL character.
delete [] iniOptions.server; // free the old buffer
iniOptions.server = new char[length]; // allocate your own buffer
strncpy(iniOptions.server, server, length); // copy the characters
```

For this to work you have to make `myclass::server` non-const, and you have to initialize it to NULL in the constructor and delete it in the destructor.

A better way to deal with this situation would be use `std::string` instead of `char *` for `muclass::server`.  This way `std::string` would take care of memory management for you, and the code would be exception-safe.

If you make `muclass::server` an `std::string`, then you simply do

```
const char* server = ini.GetValue("", "server", "");
iniOptions.server = std::string(server);
```

And you do not have to do anything with it in the constructor or the destructor.

Comment: error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
error C2664: 'strncpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers

Comment: You shouldn't be getting this error if `server` is `const char *`.  And if you make it an `std::string` then you do not need to do your own memory allocation, i. e. no `strlen()` and no `new`.