# Conversion between wchar_t* to string

Tags: c++, type-conversion, wchar-t

I was trying to create a client in c++ for a web service using a Service Model Metadata Utility Tool, I have established the communication between the two endpoints, but at the client side I receive a `wchar_t*`, how can i convert it to a string?

Note: the server side is using encoding of UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert wchar\_t\* to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339960/how-do-i-convert-wchar-t-to-stdstring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this simple function:

```
std::string wchar2string(wchar_t* str)
{
    std::string mystring;
    while( *str )
      mystring += (char)*str++;
    return  mystring;
}
```

I hope that this function can help you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::wstring` which has a constructor that takes `wchar_t*`.