# Conversion of wchar_t* to string

Tags: c++, string, winapi, type-conversion, wchar-t

How can I convert an `wchar_t*` array to an `std::string` varStr in win32 console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339960/how-do-i-convert-wchar-t-to-stdstring

Comment: show your code, please (the Win32 API) functions

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use wstring, see this code:

```
// Your wchar_t*
wchar_t* txt = L"Hello World";
wstring ws(txt);
// your new String
string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
// Show String
cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: Completelly wrong. This fails if `txt` contains any non–ascii character. If you replace `"Hello World"` with `"…"`, then `…` becomes `&`. This *solution* is highly harmful, causing data loss.

Comment: WARNING: Use this ONLY if the source string is made of ASCII characters. As previous comment says, extended (multi-byte) Unicode characters may be lost or replaced by garbage.

Comment: The compiler will also warn about possible loss of data here.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the wstring class belonging to the namespace std. It has a constructor which accepts a parameter of the type wchar_t*.

Here is a full example of using this class.

```
wchar_t* characters=L"Test";
std::wstring string(characters);
```

You do not have to use a constructor containing String.begin() and String.end() because the constructor of std::wstring automatically allocates memory for storing the array of wchar_t and copies the array to the allocated memory.

Comment: What if you specifically need a non wide string?