# Convert vector with wchar_t numbers values to wchar_t

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion

I have something like this:

```
vector<string> elements;
```

Which contains:

```
083938F8
083938FA
083938FC
083938FE
08393900
08393902
08393904
```

And i want to convert those to wchar_t numbers (like a, A, ź, ć);

Can I? And how?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339960/how-do-i-convert-wchar-t-to-stdstring

Comment: Well, i edited my question and it's a bit more specific now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) standard conversions to translate between two different character encodings:

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring wstring_convert_from_char( const char *str )
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes( str );
}

std::string string_convert_from_wchar( const wchar_t *str )
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;
    return converter.to_bytes( str );
}
```