# reference or return - best practice

Tags: c++, function, optimization, return-value-optimization

For example we have encoding function. What is the best practice to use:

```
void Crypto::encoding(string &input, string &output)
{
    //encoding string
    output = encoded_string;
}
```

or

```
string Crypto::encoding(string &input)
{
    //encoding string
    return encoded_string;
}
```

Should we use reference or return for returning the string? As far as I know returning a string will take some time to initialize a new string that will be returned by return instruction. When working on a referenced variable I don`t waste time to initialize some new variable I just end the function.

Should we mostly use reference and make function return type void? Or we should only return data by reference when we want to return two or more variables and when we need return one variable then use return instruction?

Comment: Please use the `{}` button in the editor to format code.

Comment: Are you *seriously* worried about those "times" you speak of? Have you done profiling and determined that the string construction time is your application's bottleneck?

Answer (score 10):

Do not optimize what you did not measure.

Usually it is better (more readable) to return the result of your computation with `return`. If this takes to long because the object is too fat, you can still revert to return your result via reference parameters, but only after you proved that this will result in significant improvement of performance (measure it). E.g if you only ever encode very short strings and only do that once in a while, the overhead of copying is negligible.

Comment: +1 for the *Do not optimize what you did not measure*, Scott Meyers quote on Optimization will be apt here "You need to identify the 20% of your code which runs 90% of the run time & then try to optimize that 20% of your code." Don't remember the exact words,but yes the intended meaning was the same.

Comment: I thought is was 10%, not 20% :-)

Comment: Speaking of measuring, on g++ 4.3, the two functions run at identical speeds. http://ideone.com/sgl9W

Answer (score 7):

Copying things are usually eliminated since most modern compilers have RVO features. You can take the benefits even without c++11.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports the C++11 standard and [r-value references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) then returning a std::string by value is actually quite efficient. Prior to this feature the answers might have been a little different since you'd be relying only on the compiler performing [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

I would say that using a return value is probably more natural and also means you can assign the result to a constant local variable or class member to avoid accidental modification, e.g.

```
const std::string result = crypo.encoding("blah");
```

Or

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    Someclass(Crypto& crypto, const std::string& input) :
        m_output(crypo.encoding(input))
    {
    }

private:
    const std::string m_output;
};
```

Just ensure that you *don't* return by const value as this will inhibit move semantics.

Answer (score 2):

I use references. That allows the implementor to make and abstract the choice, without taxing the client heavily (some cases matter, some will not).

I also use them for consistent style - I don't like seeing public interfaces that pass by *details of their implementation*.

The transients and copies can be expensive - it varies greatly by the type you are passing. To return by value indicates the type should be trivially constructible, swappable, copyable, movable. The compiler *can* make some great optimizations in this area (RVO/move), but you can also make informed decisions to minimize expensive operations in your implementations. Once you're no longer using types everybody knows the copy characteristics for, then choosing how to return becomes very complex, so I just keep it simple and favor references.

Passing a reference has a few other benefits, such as when the client prefers to use a subclass of the type that is passed.

Another benefit if you need an optimized program: I will often delete the copy ctor and `operator=` if they are not trivial or possible. Passing by mutable reference allows you to work with types which are not copy/assignable.

In the strict scope of `std::string` used in this question: Returning a `std::string` by value is quite common, and many optimizations have been made specifically for this case - RVO, COW, and moves are some notable ones. As Voo mentioned in the comments below, returning by value is often easier to read. In the case of `std::string` and higher level programs, returning by value is not likely to be an issue, but it's important to measure in order to understand the costs involved for the standard library implementations you are using if performance is important (which your question suggests may be the case).

An important consideration is that if you are trying to improve upon an existing program, be sure you understand how the implementation executes, and learn how you can use the types most effectively when performance is important. Implementations may be written and optimized for *actual* use, which means that they may be pessimistic and second guessing you in some cases, and your attempts to improve performance may already be implemented or unconventional use of the type may *degrade* performance. Typical resizing behaviour of a `std::vector` is an obvious example. Taking the high performance road does add a lot of time and complexity regarding what you need to know to achieve the best results, and this obviously varies by implementations you use and also by the types you are using. If performance *is* critical and worth nontrivial time investments, learning the operation of the types you use is a worthwhile endeavor which can lead to significant gains.

I should also add that I work in the low levels quite often - Where performance is critical and/or resources are limited. There can be many restrictions, including no exceptions, no locks (also implies no heap allocations), minimal abstraction costs, and even restricted use of dynamic polymorphism. It can be considered a fairly demanding domain, even for C++. I choose reference for the core low level pieces, but I will relax that rule if I know a program will be used only in higher level domains or unit tests.

Comment: @anonymous_downvoter That doesn't help much, unless you justify your action.

Comment: While I really think that just returning the object leads to simpler and easier to read code, you certainly make a reasonable argument here, so +1 - being able to get rid of copy ctor and operator= is really nice and I'd love to do that more often.. well nothing's perfect.

Comment: @Voo Yes, I agree that returning by value is quite often easier to read (esp. when the type is as simple `std::string`). I'm going to add a few details/background to this answer now that I've reread it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

With the new standard C++11, you can use the second variant because of the new move semantics.

Most probably, though, your compiler still only supports an older standard.
In this case, your first example does not provoke any copying and is better.

Comment: sounds like a micro optimization

Comment: @VJo: Not really, If your string has millions of characters or if you call this function million times then you only have to touch half of the memory in the first example than in the second. That is one of the reasons why move semantics were introduced in the first place.

Comment: The second probably also does not invoke copying, see RVO/NRVO or http://stackoverflow.com/q/1394229/79455

Comment: Unless a deep copy is performed (in the example, it is not the case), it is a micro optimization

Answer (score 1):

I'll go on record as saying: probably neither one.

Your `encode` looks to me a lot like it could/should be a generic algorithm that should really use iterators instead of dealing directly with strings at all.

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
void encode(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, OutputIterator result) {
    while (begin!=end)
        *result++ = encode_byte(*begin++);
}
```

This way you can (for example) easily re-use exactly the same code to encode data directly from an input stream (via an `std::istream_iterator`) to an output stream (via an `std::ostream_iterator`).

This also generally eliminates most questions about efficiency.

Comment: Just wondering: If I feed `Sammich::Iterator`s to your function, how does `encode_byte()` know how to encode a sammich? You would also need to supply the encoding algorithm to be truly generic, but all that would be left from your function is the iteration so it should rather be named `for_each`... ;-)

Comment: @EricSchaefer: it obviously doesn't automatically gain special knowledge of how to encode every possible input type. It can, however, be (mostly) independent of the type of container holding that data.

Comment: Surely that's just std::transform you are describing?

Comment: @BleepBloop: Yes and no. Depending on the encoding involved, `transform` might indeed be just the ticket. OTOH, `transform` expects an exact 1:1 mapping from input elements to output elements. It would be difficult (at best) to apply to something like converting UTF-8 to UCS-4 (or vice versa) where the number of inputs and outputs differ.

Comment: But your function template is exactly the same apart from calling a fixed operation rather than it being an argument. You're still doing the same 1:1 mapping here - each iteration requires a new output element to be written (*result++) and a new input element to be consumed (*begin++).

Comment: @BleepBloop: Yes, the *demo* code above doesn't show any differences. But it's just *demo* code. When/if you write the real thing, you use `transform` if it's suitable, and write something else of your own otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I like the second version better, because it looks more like a mathematical function. If you are only returning string you should be good performance wise.