# Return Value Optimization

Tags: c++, performance, return-value, copy-constructor

Consider the following two implementations of the same function

```
Object foo()
{
    Object ret;
    ret.a.set(...);
    ret.b.set(...);
    return ret;
}

Object foo()
{
    A a;
    a.set(...);

    B b;
    b.set(...);

    return Object(a, b);
}
```

Suppose that A::set and B::set must be called after construction. In addition, suppose that Object, A, and B all have move constructors that do not copy a significant amount of data. Finally, assume the compiler performs both RVO and NRVO.

Which of these is more efficient with respect to object construction?

Comment: Depends on `Object`, compiler optimization, etc. Just profile it

Comment: [Understanding return value optimization and returning temporaries - C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394229)

Comment: Why does the constructor not take the parameters it needs to fully construct the object. As long as this is not a bottleneck (and you should be able to prove that). Then the code should be written in a way that is easiest to write and maintain.

Comment: I am most curious about the efficiency from a theoretical standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If this implementation were to use 3 sub-objects (A, B, C) then the latter would seem more efficient as there would be fewer member value calls to the newly created Object. I don't think it really makes a difference, though. I would just go with whichever one you feel is the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming -- since you did not give much context -- that the members a and b are vector-like and that the set function "fills" this vector-like object with elements ... and assuming that the two-parameter constructor for Object copy constructs the members a and b from the parameters ... and assuming that your compiler is able to do NRVO and not just RVO (which is pretty common by now) ... the first function should be more efficient since you don't have to copy a and b that way.